# pip ssl certificate error OSX installing scrapy

Tags: python, macos, ssl, https, pip

Getting an error from pip when installing scrapy on OS X El Capitan

```
    ~ pip install scrapy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyOpenSSL in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cssselect>=0.9 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): queuelib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): parsel>=0.9.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)

Collecting cffi>=1.4.1 (from cryptography>=1.3->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [Errno 2] No such file or directory - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cffi>=1.4.1 (from cryptography>=1.3->pyOpenSSL->scrapy) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cffi>=1.4.1 (from cryptography>=1.3->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
```

Have tried to reinstall pip, python & homebrew
Scrubbed directories as well, but nothing working

Tried independently install cryptography, installing via brew — no dice

Answer (score 0):

The entire environment was broken.

I deleted the following folders out of ~/usr/lib/

- python2.7
- python3.4
- python3.5

Then did the following

```
brew uninstall python
brew update
brew upgrade
brew doctor
brew cleanup
brew install python
pip install scrapy
```

All works now!